# Regular expression starting and ending with parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I could not find a correct solution this in PHP. My string patterns will be like

```
[{}]
[{1}]
[{1,3}]
[{1,3,4}] 
etc..
```

And I tried using the regular expression like `"/^\[\{\d|,*\}\]$/i"`. But it is not working perfectly.

Basically the string should start with "[{" (one time), end with "}]" (one time) and contain numeric characters and "," in between.

Hope this makes my query clear.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you tell us what you think this part is doing? `\d|,*`

Comment: You may find this useful, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @meagar : \d gives [0-9], '|' means OR, "," is another character allowed and "*" means any number of times this sequence can appear.

IanJamieson : I already tried that. But I found it useful for checking and not building the regex. May be I am missing something?

Comment: You're right, but the that's not going to match your examples. `\d|,*` would match `[0-9]` **or** zero or more commas, meaning it would match things like `[{5}]` **or** `[{,,,,,,,}]`, but it will never match both commas and numbers. You can also safely drop the `/i`, which makes the regex case-insensitive. Since you have no characters with upper/lower case, that can't help.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't be storing these values in a database to link records together, would you?

Comment: You are right, I already dropped that. sorry, didnt updated here. :(

No, i will be using the preg_match to trace if the input is of this format.

Comment: Perhaps this is too off topic but why `[{...}]` instead of simple `[...]`? Then you could use PHP's function `json_decode` to easily parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(\[{[0-9,]+}\])
```

It will match all cases where there is a mix of digits and commas between the [{ and }]

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/bP2kU5)

Comment: Should really be more specific, I don't think we want to match `,,5,,` or the like.

Comment: emh : it works like a charm for my requirement, cuz I already am getting a sanitized input with no repeating commas without a number in between. However, if we want a strict match, then meager's viewpoint is to be considered as well. But thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
^\[\{((\d+,)*\d+)?\}\]$
```

Comment: Won't work if he has something like `[{1,3}],[{1,3,4}]` and wants to capture every "group". OP didn't give enough detail.

Comment: Gives "preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found"

Comment: @PratipGhosh this is pure regex. You have to wrap it with `/`